# Fotorama- how to update from Github

Tags: javascript, jquery, github, fotorama

A fix for a Fotorama bug was in a recent update of the plugin on Github:

https://github.com/artpolikarpov/fotorama/commit/1810d59eecc927fbef14cb6f8a1611047a2404fb

I have the latest Fotorama version (downloaded from http://fotorama.io/) and am still experiencing the bug- I tried replacing the fotorama.js file with both an unminified and minified version of the updated fotorama.js file from the link above, but then the plugin does not work at all.  How can I implement this update?

Comment: Try with the uncompressed http://fotorama.s3.amazonaws.com/4.5.2/fotorama-4.5.2.dev.zip and see if the issue persists.

Comment: It still does-- the plugin itself works but the first slide does not show the caption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The creator of the Fotorama plugin solved it!  For anyone else having this issue, here is what he said to do:

> I believe that you start listening to fotorama:show event after fotorama get initialized, so you’re loosing the very first event.
>
> You should start listening first, and then initialize fotorama manually.
>
> In my example everything works as expected, look in console: http://artpolikarpov.github.io/fotorama/test/events.html

So I moved the listening function that generates the captions:

```
$('.fotorama').on('fotorama:show', function (e, fotorama) {...}
```

before the Fotorama initialization:

```
$('.fotorama').fotorama({...})
```

and now it is working beautifully for me. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The OP mentions that even the latest uncompressed version of that script (http://fotorama.s3.amazonaws.com/4.5.2/fotorama-4.5.2.dev.zip) doesn't work:

> the plugin itself works but the first slide does not show the caption

That means one need to add a new [issue to the artpolikarpov/fotorama project](https://github.com/artpolikarpov/fotorama/issues) in order to describe and report that bug.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, first caption was not showing. This was using the  "div" Fotorama approach (necessary to create links per image).
Adding **data-auto="false"** to the main fotorama div solved it.
Hope this will save someone a few hours...